# Mask Image color programmatically - Think Themes for Images

Tags: php, jquery, css, html, image-manipulation

Is there a way to change the color of a image that is hosted on another site?

Link to example image: http://www.opensource.org/files/garland_logo.png

[image]

So is there a way to mask it with another color? and only certain colors like change or overlay the light green but leave the dark green border alone?
Any thoughts ideas?

Comment: What good is a logo if you go changing its appearance?

Comment: My idea was to theme the logo. I have a simple logo with a couple of colors and didn't want to make several new logos with just the color change. Would like to know if I could use the one logo and theme/Mask it to another color? This way I could keep the one image instead of making X number of new images every time I need a new theme. I was thinking I would have to make a transparent logo and just set the background but not sure if this is the best approach as I might have a few to convert this way as well

Comment: Do you want to do the colour changing server-side using PHP, or client-side using JavaScript/"HTML5" [canvas]? Is the image always hosted on another domain, or is that just for the example?

Comment: The image could be hosted on another domain so I'm thinking Client but would also like a server side implementation. But most (if not all) the images will be locally hosted

Comment: @Phil Pafford -Right, that makes sense. I thought you were going to use it on a logo that you have no association to.

Comment: Also looking for a server side solution as well? PHP/Perl/Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A client-side solution: http://camanjs.com/

You should be able to do it by changing the hue of the image: http://camanjs.com/docs/built-in#hue

Canvas is subject to the same-origin policy, so [the documentation](http://camanjs.com/docs) includes details on how to make this work with remote images.

Browser support for canvas: http://caniuse.com/canvas

Comment: I'm going to have to play with this but this looks great, Thanks! +1

Comment: hmm do you have a server side solution as well? PHP/Perl/Python?

Comment: @Phill Pafford: My go-to solution for any kind of image manipulation in PHP is [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php). You probably want [`-modulate`](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/color_mods/#modulate) to change the hue. Google "imagemagick php" for instructions on how to get started.

Comment: Another useful link: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagick-modulateimage.php